# Which Driving direction is selected if you use MapQuest

Tags: algorithm, graph-traversal

[image: Given graph]

**Question**: Which Driving direction is selected from Node 1 to Node 7 if you use MapQuest?

I was asked to solve this and I have no idea how to? Can someone explain to me how to approach this problem?